# CSS for top image (wide screen, mobile view)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a question regarding website design and css solution. The current situation as it is now, I have a wordpress website with a onepager theme.
On the top I have an image, which takes almost full screen with Title. So my questions is regarding that image and different browser/window sizes.

For example for my current screen size it is adjusted very well, as it should be, BUT if i open on a large / wide screen, the image is incresed in width, but this way, I don't see what is lower, the image becomes wide with the same proporties to width so in height I only see a small part of the image and that is logical.
Another problem is the mobile view of that image.

Here is basically the sample: jthemes.org/wp/uniset/demo9

- Try to open on a wide screen and see result ...
- Try other sizes ...
- Open on mobile ..

What is the best way to resolve this, what is the most common and best approach?
What should I do?

Snippets:
CSS:

```
.vc_custom_1525172849260 {
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    padding-top: 240px !important;
    padding-bottom: 180px !important;
    background-image: url(http://jthemes.org/wp/uniset/demo9/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/2018/05/hero-8.jpg?id=230) !important;
    background-position: center !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
```

Html

```
<div data-vc-full-width="true" data-vc-full-width-init="true" class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid bg-scroll vc_custom_1525172849260 vc_row-has-fill vc_row-o-content-middle vc_row-flex" style="position: relative; left: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; width: 1165px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;"><div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-10"><div class="vc_column-inner vc_custom_1519925212553"><div class="wpb_wrapper">                
        <div class="title-subtitle-wrap text-left ">

            <!-- Title -->  
            <h3 style="font-size:110px; color: #222222">FIND YOUR TIPPING POINT</h3>
                        <!-- Big Text -->
                <p class="p-lg text-left" style="color: #333333">Nullam tempor sapien, eget gravida. Donec enim ipsum porta justo integer at odio velna vitae auctor integer congue magna impedit magna viverra</p>            
                    </div>
        </div></div></div><div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-2"><div class="vc_column-inner "><div class="wpb_wrapper"></div></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It simply can be achieved with width: 100% css styling. Or just wrap it inside a div tag.

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://jthemes.org/wp/uniset/demo9/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/2018/05/banner-3-img.png">

<div>
  <img src="http://jthemes.org/wp/uniset/demo9/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/2018/05/banner-3-img.png">
</div>
```

Comment: but the image is a background-image:url(.....), and by doing this it will not be fully wisible it will be wide but the height ... will be abruted, or am i mistaken?

Comment: Please give me your code snippet so it will be easier to solve your issue.

Comment: Updated the original post with css and html piece

Comment: I can see that you set the width to 1165px there, change it to 100%.

Comment: Yes it will be wide, but it will be only visible for less than half of an image, do you know what i mean? If you open an example site on widescreen 27+ inch you will see maybe only females head, but if you open on a smaller screen you will see the back of the body and where she sits on ...

Comment: For that you can make use of height: 1vw;